# Replace jQuery from div to id

Tags: jquery

Is there any way to replace a content using jQuery from - let's say,

```
<html>
    <body>
        <div class="information1">
             This is the information.
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

to

```
<html>
    <body>
       <div id="information">              
            <div class="information1">
                 This is the information.
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$("div.information1").wrap("<div id='information'></div>");
```

More on the `wrap()` function here: http://api.jquery.com/wrap

Comment: Didn't know "wrap" existed.  Awesome!

Comment: Doh!  Beat me to it.  +1 anyway ;-)

Answer (score 0):

you could try something like:

```
$('#information').append('<div class="information>Text here</div>');
```